# How to see if another date is older than today's date

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following code in C#:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(strDueDate); //strDueDate = '03-25-2015'
string strToday = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm-dd-yyyy");
DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(strToday); // this is displaying 9/3/2015 12:00:00 AM
if (dt < dt1)
{
    dvShowReopen.Visible = false;
}
```

What I am looking to do is take the `strDueDate` and compare against today. If it is less than today, than set the visibility to false.

How can I achieve it.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString("mm-dd-yyyy");` gives you the minutes instead of the months.

Comment: `dt < DateTime.Now` (or Today) was too easy?

Comment: Why not just `if (dt.Date < DateTime.Today)`?

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?

Comment: Why would you take a date, convert it to a string, and then convert it back to a date for comparison?

Answer (score 4):

If you looking for only date part's comparison with *compare against today* sentence, you can just use [`Date` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your `dt` and compare it with [`DateTime.Today`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
if (dt.Date < DateTime.Today)
```

If you looking for full part comparison with `dt` and your current local time, just compare it with [`Now` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
if (dt < DateTime.Now)
```

You don't need these string representations. Every time you generate string representation of a DateTime with compare another DateTime, you should aware that you are doing something **wrong**.

Let's look at your code line by line what is doing exactly.

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("03-25-2015");
```

This line will generate a `DateTime` (you are lucky this is a [standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) as `25/3/2015 12:00:00 AM`. Since your string don't have time part, it will be midnight *by default*.

```
string strToday = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm-dd-yyyy");
```

This will generate a string for your current local time with minute (**not** Month), day and year. Because [`mm` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#mmSpecifier) is for minutes but [`MM` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#MM_Specifier) is for months. When you run this code, looks like your current local time minute is `9`. (*Based on next line*)

```
DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(strToday);
```

This line will generate a DateTime based on your `03-09-2015` string (because previous line generate this string) and since your string still don't have any time part, it will generate `9/3/2015 12:00:00 AM` as a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 2):

Will this code not work?

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 3, 25);
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;

if (dt < dt1)
{
    dvShowReopen.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: You are using a static date.

Answer (score 1):

And why the conversion? You should be fine with :

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(strDueDate); //strDueDate = '03-25-2015'
if (dt.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 0)
{
    dvShowReopen.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(strDueDate);
if ((dt - DateTime.Now).TotalDays < 1)
{
    dvShowReopen.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another thought on how to do it...

```
 if (DateTime.TryParse(strDueDate, out dt))
   dvShowReopen.Visible = (dt.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 0);
 else
   dvShowReopen.Visible = false;
```